# Entity Framework- Doing a join when there won't always be a match

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am building a query in entity framework, im trying do do a right join, but it on the child object.

I have a table of of calls, that logs all phone calls

```
Call:    -Id-      -PhoneNumber-    -CallTime-  
          1         101             10
          2         102             20
          3         102             10
```

There is a PhoneNumbers  table that has phone numbers of known numbers

```
   PhoneNumber:    -Id-      -PhoneNumber-    -PersonId-  
                    1         102             10
                    2         103             11
                    3         104             12
```

And finally there is a person table that has there name, the reason for this structure is a person could have many phone numbers.

```
   Person:         -Id-      -Name-       
                    10         John         
                    11         Paul             
                    12         George
```

What I want is a list of name off all the calls with the persons name if known instead of there number
so

```
Call:    -Id-      -PhoneNumber-    -CallTime-  
          1         101               10
          2         John              20
          3         John              10
```

I have tried the following, but there setting of the phone number did not work, I know its the join, but cant seem to work it out.

```
 var query = from call in Call    
                join phoneNumber in PhoneNumber on call.PhoneNumber              equals phoneNumber.PhoneNumber  
                join person      in Person  on phoneNumber.PersonID       equals person.Id  
                into r_join
                from rEmpty in r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            
 select new {
               call.Id,
               PhoneNumber = rEmpty?.Name ?? call.Number
               call.CallTime
 }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with the code - it seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is a list of name off all the calls with the persons name if known instead of there number so

Assuming your Phone numbers are unique:

```
var result = dbContext.PhoneCalls.Select(phoneCall => new
{
    Id = phoneCall.Id,
    PhoneNumber = phoneCall.PhoneNumber,

    // from this phone call, get the corresponding item in table PhoneNumbers
    // from this PhoneNumber get the Person that the foreign key PersonId refers to
    // from this Person get the name
    PersonName = dbContext.PhoneNumbers
        .Where(phoneNumber => phoneNumber.PhoneNumber == phoneCall.PhoneNumber)
        .Select(phoneNumber => dbContext.Persons
                               .Where(person => person.Id == phoneNumber.PersonId)
                               .Select(person.Name))
        .FirstOrDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what went with, not sure if this will give me a N+1 issue, but the list is paged........ so wont worry about it.